# What can cause a webapp I deployed to Tomcat to be accessible via the root path?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I copy-paste-deployed a webapp to a local installation of Tomcat 6 (I place "my-app" folder under "webapps"). I expected my app to be accessible via http://localhost:8080/my-app/.

Instead, I find that it is accessible directly via the root path (http://localhost:8080/).

What configuration can be the cause of this?

This is my context.xml (comments stripped)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Comment: Can you include the context information from the config please.

Comment: Maybe you have `ROOT.war` in you webapps with exactly the same application? Could an IDE have copied it there?

Comment: Sorry can you paste the whole Host section please.

Comment: @denisk - I have a ROOT folder in my webapps, but it seems to contain the legit Tomcat root. I am using IntelliJ, I think this is the source of my confusion - I see now it's using another folder as CATALINA_BASE.

Comment: @Jon - this is the entire file, there's no more.

Comment: @ripper234: oh yes, if you're starting your tomcat from intellij - an app will be available via the root. And you don't have to copy an application to `webapps` folder - intellij will make it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using IntelliJ, the web path to your application is specified in `Edit Configuration -> Deployment` tab. You can click on an artifact you're deploying and change its web path in `Application context` dropdown (which is `/` by default)

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you copied and pasted but take at look at the ROOT.XML file in Tomcat and see whether that's configured to serve the application instead.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html